# Module not found nodejs?

Tags: node.js, modulenotfounderror

I am trying to create a simple request
However I am getting the following error

```
node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:936
throw err;
^

Error: Cannot find module 'C:\Users\wgupta\Backend\temp\index.js'
at Function.Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:933:15)
at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:778:27)
at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:77:12)
at node:internal/main/run_main_module:17:47 {
  code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
  requireStack: []
}
```

This is the code I have written

```
const app = require('express')()

const bodyParser = require('body-parser')
app.use(bodyParser.json())
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true })) 

app.post('/',  (req, res, next) => {
  console.log(req.body)
  res.json(req.body.adMeta);
})

const port = 3000;

app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log(`Example app listening on port ${port}`)
})
```

Comment: Sounds like you are just running `node index.js` in a directory which doesn't have an `index.js` in it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There might be some mistake in the package.json. Also, I see something off in the code with express.

```
const express = require('express'); 
const app = express.app();

const bodyParser = require('body-parser')
app.use(bodyParser.json()) // no need to use body parser in express 4+
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true })) 

app.post('/',  (req, res, next) => {
  console.log(req.body)
  res.json(req.body.adMeta);
})

const port = 3000;

app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log(`Example app listening on port ${port}`)
})
```

Note: try to install all dependencies correctly. If you are using express-generator for the project, you need to run different command to run the project else use `node index.js`.

Answer (score 0):

try following command

remove node_modules and package-lock.json

```
rm -rf node_modules package-lock.json
```

then run following command to install dependencies

```
npm install
```

finally, run your package by following command.

```
npm start
```

Answer (score 0):

i would look better at package.json file, you are using require -> so have proper type setted in package.json. Because nothing really look wrong w ur code. Are you having the packages in node_modules or any diffrent way?